# How can I change the text on the button when user selects one option from the dropdown? (angular.js)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a webpage with angular.js and bootstrap and I have a component exactly like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/xkL15guj/)
When user unfolds the menu and choses the action - I want to change the text on the button. So far my code looks as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="queryUsers()">Show data from last hour</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a ng-click="queryUsersFromYesterday()">Show data from yesterday</a></li>
         <li><a ng-click="queryUsersFromLastWeek()">Show data from last week</a></li>
         <li><a  ng-click="queryUsersFromLastMonth()">Show data from last month</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Right now when user clicks: show data from last week - the menu disappears, but the button still has a text: show data from last hour. How can I dynamically change the text on the button?

Answer (score 0):

I'd maintain one flag inside the scope, that will only once set to true

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="buttonClicked = true;">
    <span ng-class="buttonClicked? 'caret': 'sr-only'" 
      ng-bind="buttonClicked? 'Toggle Dropdown': 'Toggled'">
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Could you show me an example based on my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xkL15guj/ ? I'm not exactly sure what do you mean here, sorry..